# Why is my page value isn't updating for URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard";

const PopularMovies = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const bearerToken = process.env.MY_BEARER_TOKEN;

  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + bearerToken,
      },
    };
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?language=en-US&page=" +
          page,
        options
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
      setMovies((prevMovies) => [...prevMovies, ...data.results]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
    if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5 && !loading) {
      fetchMovies();
    }
  };
  console.log(page);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-10 gap-6 justify-center items-center">
      {movies.map((movie) => (
        <MovieCard key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PopularMovies;
```

> I want to fetch new movies data by updating the value of page from 1
> to 2 and so on whenever user reach at the end of page. Everything
> working fine, page value is updating correctly but my URL still taking
> value 1 and fetching data for same page 1.
> please explain me in detail about what could be wrong over here?
> am I updating state correctly or not?

Comment: Hi, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - I know you mentioned you can't paste it, most likely because you've surrounding your explanatory text in backticks (making the system think you've posted code only), I've removed those now. See [formatting](/help/formatting) if you need assistance on formatting your question.

Comment: Sorry , modified now.

Answer (score 0):

read `urlSeachParamas` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for setting your url

Comment: thanks will do that, but I would like to know that why is my above code not working? like why it is not taking updated value of page state variable.

Comment: Okay so I tried to update the page value using useRef and it's working fine now, Still I want to know that why it was not working with the useState but working with useRef.

Answer (score 0):

When you're updating state in React, especially in asynchronous operations like fetching data, it's crucial to remember that state updates are not immediate. They are scheduled to happen in the future, so referencing a state variable right after updating it might give you its old value, not the new one.

In your case, you're updating the page state and immediately using it to fetch data, which might be causing the issue. Instead, consider calculating the next page number first, use that for fetching, and then update your state with this new value.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard";

const PopularMovies = () => {
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const bearerToken = process.env.MY_BEARER_TOKEN;

 const fetchMovies = async () => {
 const nextPage = page + 1; // Calculate the next page number
 const options = {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
     accept: "application/json",
     Authorization: "Bearer " + bearerToken,
    },
  };
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?language=en-US&page= {nextPage}`,
     options
     );
     const data = await res.json();
     console.log(data);
     setPage(nextPage); // Update the page state with the new value
     setMovies((prevMovies) => [...prevMovies, ...data.results]);
    } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
   };

   useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
     const handleScroll = () => {
     const { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight } = document.documentElement;
     if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight - 5 && !loading) {
      fetchMovies();
     }
   };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
    }, [loading]); // Adding loading to the dependency array

   console.log(page);

   return (
    <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-10 gap-6 justify-center items-center">
    {movies.map((movie) => (
      <MovieCard key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
     ))}
     </div>
    );
    };

    export default PopularMovies;
```

Comment: Alright let's say It'll take old value since it's async and state never get's update immediately but at some point it should take the older value which has been updated? am I wrong, like after some time it should at least take next updated value of page e.g. 2 or 3 maybe but why taking the intial value 1 always?